# Confusion with Fortran submodules and gcc compliation flag -Wuse-without-only

Tags: oop, gcc, module, fortran, gfortran

What is the remedy for this gcc Fortran compilation warning?

```
USE statement at (1) has no ONLY qualifier
```

The warning occurs when using submodules in gcc 6.0, 6.1, 6.2, and, 7.0.

The full compilation sequence and warning:

```
$ gfortran -c -Wuse-without-only -o mod_module.o mod_module.f08
$ gfortran -c -Wuse-without-only -o mod_module_sub.o mod_module_sub.f08
mod_module_sub.f08:1:19:

 submodule ( mModule ) mSubModule
                   1
Warning: USE statement at (1) has no ONLY qualifier [-Wuse-without-only]
$ gfortran -c -Wuse-without-only -o demonstration.o demonstration.f08
$ gfortran  -o demonstration demonstration.o mod_module.o mod_module_sub.o
$ ./demonstration 
 this + that =    3.00000000    
 expected value is 3
```

Main program (demonstration.f08):

```
program demonstration
    use mModule, only : myType
    implicit none
    type ( myType ) :: example
        example % this = 1.0
        example % that = 2.0
        call example % adder ( )
        write ( *, * ) 'this + that = ', example % other
        write ( *, * ) 'expected value is 3'
    stop
end program demonstration
```

Module (mod_module.f08):

```
module mModule
    implicit none
    type :: myType
        real :: this, that, other
    contains
        private
        procedure, public :: adder => adder_sub
    end type myType

    private :: adder_sub

    interface
        module subroutine adder_sub ( me )
            class ( myType ), target :: me
        end subroutine adder_sub
    end interface

end module mModule
```

Submodule (mod_module_sub.f08):

```
submodule ( mModule ) mSubModule  ! <=== problematic statement
    implicit none
contains
    module subroutine adder_sub ( me )
        class ( myType ), target :: me
        me % other = me % this + me % that
    end subroutine adder_sub
end submodule mSubModule
```

That is, what is the proper way to specify submodules? The flag `-Wuse-without-only` is essential in compilation of longer codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your perspective, it is just a compiler bug.  File a bug report and wait for it to get fixed (or fix it yourself).

(An alternative perspective is that because that code gives submodules access to all the entities of their host, whether required or not, the warning is appropriate.  But limiting host association requires F2015 support.)

`-Wuse-without-only` is just a warning to help enforce a particular programming style (one that I don't think is particularly useful).  It cannot be "essential" to compile any code, short or long.  If the warning bothers you in the meantime, remove that option.

Comment: None of my codes would pass that option without warning.